# Can I use a comma between "so «adjective»" and "that «clause»"?

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation

Now I am writing a scientific paper, and I want to write a sentence as follows:

> **A** has a chemical composition so similar to *that* of **B** *that* it also has a high potential.

As you can see, the first 'that' is used to substitute for 'chemical composition', and the second 'that' is used to introduce the following clause.

However, I am so worried because it seems to confusing due to the repetition of 'that'. (Because I am not a native, I cannot make a sentence with assurance...)

So, I tried to use a comma before the second 'that', but I don't know if it will be a correct sentence.

Comment: I've seen a few questions on ELL worrying about whether it's okay to use the same word twice in a sentence. (See [this questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/807), for example.) Usually, those fears are unfounded. There's nothing wrong with your sentence with two instances of _that_.

Comment: Clarity is always best: "...similar to the composition of B, which has a high potential as well." Use _which_, but not _that_, when the information introduced is unnecessary for identifying the thing or person described. In this case, _which_ has to be set off with a comma.

Comment: @Sara I think not. The second *that* here is not a relativizer but a subordinator marking the complement of *so*; it is not *B* but *A* which "also has a high potential".

Comment: Thanks  a lot@StoneyB I really didn't see it that way.

Comment: @Sara That[!] is an example of why I like to be very sparing in the use of *that* :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are times when a comma may be added for the sake of readability. For example:

> Those that know, do. Those that understand, teach.
>
> – [Aristotle](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/aristotle_378331)

However, I think your sentence reads fine and needs no comma. Moreover, sentences that contain the word *that* two times are not uncommon. As a matter of fact, sometimes the two *that's* appear [consecutively](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem):

> Don't be seduced into thinking that that which does not make a profit is without value.
>
> – [Arthur Miller](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/arthur_miller_385648)

If you still insist your sentence seems awkward, here's what I might do instead of trying to fix it with a comma:

> **A** also has a high potential, because it has a chemical composition so similar to that of **B**.

Comment: Some more helpful reading: [_When should I accept my answer?_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) and [_Are thanks for answers unnecessary?_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744) Cheers.

Comment: So, you're saying that that "that" that follows "that" is not wrong?

Comment: If you really want to use a comma to split up the long sentence, change the connecting words to something like "A has a chemical composition that is very similar to B, and therefore it also has a high potential."

Answer (score 13):

SUPPLEMENTAL to J.R.'s answer:
A comma would not be appropriate before the second *that*: this *that* marks the complement of *so ...* and consequently should not be disjoined from it.

As J.R. remarks, the double use of *that* is not really problematic. It's really two different words, demonstrative *that* and subordinator *that*. They are only historically and orthographically the "same" word. In Present-day English speech they aren't even pronounced the same way: the demonstrative is always stressed, and the subordinator is always de-stressed and pronounced with a reduced vowel.

I confess, however, that I personally find the use of two orthographic ‹*that*›s in different senses a little jarring in written English when they're so near one another. My own solution would be to recast the sentence to eliminate the first—perhaps something like this:

> **A**'s chemical composition is so similar to **B**'s that it also has a high potential.

Comment: You don't even need the genitive. *"The chemical composition of A is so similar to B, that A also has a high potential."*

Comment: @StianYttervik you don't need the comma in your example either - and IMO (native British English speaker) it would be better without the comma.

Comment: @alephzero yeah on second glance I agree. Not native speaker =P

Comment: I don't like @StianYttervik's suggestion; it implies that *A* and *the chemical composition of A* are the same thing.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Did you intend to day that 'it implies that B and the chemical composition of A are the same thing.'? And, do you still think that the used of 'that of B' is correct?

Comment: @AntonSherwood I am biased: I am a chemist. But this also provides me with some grammatical memory on how chemists talk about these things. I still think it is obvious, when you narrow down and say *The chemical composition of A" you compare it correspondingly (but without having to specify it) to the chemical composition of B. Let's take it to another adjective. The color of A is so close to B that A also has overall high emissivity. See? the sentence works fine, and I don't think anyone would claim I imply A to be the same thing as color of A.

Comment: @StianYttervik As I understand, "The color of A is so close to that of B that~" is strictly correct sentence, but "The color of A is so close to B that~" is also correct because the  meaning of the sentence can be fully understood by anybody, right?

Comment: @Sungil They are all fully understood. The subjects in these sentences are "the color of A" and "the color of B" and they are connected by a verb (being) which is a linking verb and the full verb would be "to be similar".  That is transitive - that is why I defined 2 subjects. Now, the discussion here is how to represent these 2 subjects, and you are technically not changing the grammar - the structure of the sentence. It is allowed to omit subjects when they are known. "The man is similar" (to whom? if it is known, if it was discussed just before, the sentence is OK)

Comment: @Sungil: no and yes, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct to use a comma before the second *that* is a good one.

Commas do not have hard and fast rules, and as J.R. points out, there are indeed times when a comma may be added for the sake of readability.

I, however, respectfully disagree with J.R.'s *opinion* about the use of a comma before your second *that*. I think that doing so makes your sentence clearer, and more easily understood. And that is the point of good writing; not being so obsessed with rules like "Don't start a sentence with 'And'", and "Don't use a comma unless it's absolutely necessary".

My rule is this: If a comma helps me to convey meaning, and if it helps my writing sound more conversational, I almost always use one.